# Build stylus from the git repo

Tags: javascript, makefile, stylus

I'm trying to get a stylus.js with the latest version, 1 file with all the features.

I cloned the git repo https://github.com/stylus/stylus and ran make stylus.js

```
aaas-iMac:stylus aaa$ make stylus.js
make: *** No rule to make target `stylus.js'.  Stop.
```

But I get that error with no rule. I see a Makefile in the repo, I don't understand what the problem is? How do I get a stylus.js with everything in 1 file? I want to do compiling clientside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the default git branch to `client` (client-side version of Stylus):

```
git checkout client
```

Then install dependencies:

```
npm install
```

And after this run:

```
make stylus.js
```

Also you can make minified version (for it you need to install uglifyjs first with `npm install uglify-js -g`):

```
make stylus.min.js
```